# Cleverly finding the minimum of function

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

I want to cleverly find minimum of function $$f(x,y)=a(y-x)^2+bx^2$$ when $$x^2+y^2=1.$$ By **cleverly** I mean by using some smart inequalities which give lower estimate for $f,$ and which become equalities exactly when the minimum occurs. Thus, by **cleverly,** **I do not** mean Lagrange's multipliers method/finding zero of the first derivative. By doing the former, I have obtained 
$$\min{f}=a\bigg[1-{1\over 2}\bigg[\sqrt{4+{b^2 \over a^2}}-{b \over a} \bigg]\bigg],$$ which is attained for
$$x^2={{4+{b^2 \over a^2}-{b \over a}\sqrt{4+{b^2 \over a^2}}}\over{2(4+{b^2 \over a^2}})}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\cos{t},y=\sin{t}$, where $t\in [0.2\pi)$, then we have

$\begin{array}\\
f&=a-2axy+bx^2\\
&=a-2a\sin{t}\cos{t}+b\cos^2{t}\\
&=-a\sin{2t}+\displaystyle\frac{b}{2}\cos{2t}+a+\frac{b}{2}\\
&=\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{4}+a^2}\sin(2t+\phi)+a+\frac{b}{2}\\
&\geq-\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{4}+a^2}+a+\frac{b}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

where $\displaystyle\phi=\arctan(\frac{b}{-2a})\in[0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

We consider only the case $a,b>0$, of course.
Then after rescaling, we can and do assume $a,b$ are of the shape:
$$
\begin{aligned}
b &= \sin c\ ,\\
a &= \frac 12\cos c\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
In the sequel, $c$ is thus a constant in the interval between $0$ and $\pi/2$.
The variables $x,y$, constrained to $x^2+y^2=1$ are then parametrized by an unconstrained $t\in[0,2\pi)$ with 
$$
\begin{aligned}
x&=\cos t\ \\
y&=\sin t\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So we need to minimize:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(t) 
&=\cos c\frac 12(\sin t -\cos t)^2 +\sin c\cos^2 t
\\
&=\cos c\left(\cos t\cos\frac \pi4 -\sin t\sin\frac \pi4 \right)^2 +\sin c\cos^2 t
\\
&=\cos c\cos\left(t+\frac \pi4 \right)^2 +\sin c\cos^2 t
\\
&=\cos c\frac 12\left(\cos2\left(t+\frac \pi4 \right)+1\right) 
+\sin c\frac 12(\cos2 t+1)
\\
&=\frac 12\cos c\cos\left(2t+\frac \pi2 \right) 
+\frac 12\sin c\cos2 t
+\text{Constant}
\\
&=
-\frac 12\cos c\sin2t
+\frac 12\sin c\cos2 t
+\text{Constant}
\\
&=
\frac 12\sin (c-2 t)
+\text{Constant}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we have to minimize the sine part.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
f(x,y)
&=a(y-x)^2+bx^2\\
&=ay^2-2axy+ax^2+bx^2\\
&=a(1-x^2)-2axy+ax^2+bx^2\\
&=a-2axy+bx^2\\
&=a-2ax\sqrt{1-x^2}+bx^2\\
f_x(x, y)
&=-2a(\sqrt{1-x^2}-\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}})+2bx\\
&=-2a(\dfrac{1-x^2-x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}})+2bx\\
&=-2a(\dfrac{1-2x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}})+2bx\\
&=0 
\end{array}
$

when
(since I don't see any clever inequalities
I'll use brute force)

$a(\dfrac{1-2x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}})=bx
$
or
$a(1-2x^2)
=bx\sqrt{1-x^2}
$
or
$a^2(1-4x^2+4x^4)
=b^2x^2(1-x^2)
=b^2x^2-b^2x^4
$
or
$x^4(4a^2+b^2)-x^2(4a^2+b^2)+a^2
=0$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
x^2
&=\dfrac{4a^2+b^2\pm\sqrt{(4a^2+b^2)^2-4a^2(4a^2+b^2)}}{2(4a^2+b^2)}\\
&=\dfrac{4a^2+b^2\pm\sqrt{16a^4+8a^2b^2+b^4-16a^4-4a^2b^2}}{2(4a^2+b^2)}\\
&=\dfrac{4a^2+b^2\pm\sqrt{4a^2b^2+b^4}}{2(4a^2+b^2)}\\
&=\dfrac{4a^2+b^2\pm b\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}}{2(4a^2+b^2)}\\
&=\dfrac12\pm\dfrac{b}{2\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}}\\
\text{so}\\
y^2
&=1-x^2\\
&=\dfrac12\mp\dfrac{b}{2\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}}\\
\text{and}\\
f(x, y)
&=a-2a\sqrt{\dfrac12\pm\dfrac{b}{2\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}}}\sqrt{\dfrac12\mp\dfrac{b}{2\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}}}+b(\dfrac12\pm\dfrac{b}{2\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}})\\
&=a-2a\sqrt{\dfrac14-\dfrac{b^2}{4(4a^2+b^2)}}+b(\dfrac12\pm\dfrac{b}{2\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}})\\
&=a-a\sqrt{1-\dfrac{b^2}{4a^2+b^2}}+b(\dfrac12\pm\dfrac{b}{2\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}})\\
&=a-a\sqrt{\dfrac{4a^2+b^2-b^2}{4a^2+b^2}}+b(\dfrac12\pm\dfrac{b}{2\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}})\\
&=a-a\sqrt{\dfrac{4a^2}{4a^2+b^2}}+b(\dfrac12\pm\dfrac{b}{2\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}})\\
&=a-2a^2\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{4a^2+b^2}}+b(\dfrac12\pm\dfrac{b}{2\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}})\\
&=a+\dfrac{b}{2}-\dfrac{2a^2}{\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}}\pm(\dfrac{b^2}{2\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}})\\
&=a+\dfrac{b}{2}-\dfrac{4a^2\mp b^2}{2\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}}\\
\end{array}
$

If we want the minimum value,
take the lower sign,
so the min is
$a+\dfrac{b}{2}-\dfrac{4a^2+ b^2}{2\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}}
=a+\dfrac{b}{2}-\frac12\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}
=a+\dfrac{b}{2}-\sqrt{a^2+\dfrac{b^2}{4}}
$.